# Is it possible to access Snowflake external table through Looker?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables, looker

I have a snowflake external table and I need to create a looker view for it.

My team mate has created the table and I tried to browse it among other generic snowflake tables inside the respective schema and connection but for some reason it is just not showing up among other tables.Do we need to do any particular configuration to be able to see the external table in looker?

Comment: Check the permissions on the newly created external table to ensure the looker role has access to the ext table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to all tables should look the same to Looker, regardless if the table is external or not.

If Looker doesn't see it, it's probably a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes I checked with my teammate and now I am able to see the table in looker after he granted the permissions.Thank you for your help!